# Why the value of `Start of section headers` is so far back

Tags: c, linux, elf

I'd like to know why the value of `Start of section headers` is so far back as the value of `Start of program headers` is just 64.

Picture of `raedelf -a ./a.out` result.
[readelf -a ./a.out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLfVw.png)

Read `./a.out` in hexadecimal by `xdd`, from 0x580 to 0x1000, all are 0. From 0x1160 to 0x2000, all are 0, too.

It seems like 0s are filler between sections.

My code is just

```c
main()
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain it for me? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't show text in images. Copy-paste into the question instead. See [ask]. (If you have formatting issues, someone will fix them for you.)

Comment: 0x1000 is the page size.  Memory access permissions are per-page, so sections with different permissions can't share the same page (e.g. `.text` which must be executable and read-only, versus `.data` which must be non-executable and read-write).  So that accounts for the padding up to page boundaries.  That is unrelated to where the section headers live.

Comment: The zeros you see between sections are likely filler bytes. It is aligned to be a multiple of n (where n is a power of 2).

Comment: The zeros you see between sections are likely filler bytes. It is aligned to be a multiple of n (where n is a power of 2).

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone explain it for me?

The linker *builds* the section header table after it has placed all the sections, so section header table tends to be near the very end of the file.

In addition, the section header table isn't used at runtime, and thus isn't assigned to any loadable segment. Since typically the first `PT_LOAD` segment covers the ELF header itself, *it* has to have offset 0. Thus placing section header table anywhere except the end of the file will create a "gap" between segments, but such gaps are undesirable.

Comment: Can loaders ignore the section header table itself? Why can't I just `memset(start_of_section_header_table, 0, length_of_section_header_table).`
Thanks!